# How to add requests to a Facebook test user

Tags: facebook, testing, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to programmatically add requests (apprequests) to a Facebook test user so I can test the code in my application that handles Facebook requests. How can I do that? I'm using C#, and I'm hoping for an answer in the form of an HTTP request. I'm just not certain that this is possible, and if it's possible, what's the API?

Comment: You mean an apprequest? You do it the same way you would for any user, just with a target user id of the test user.

Comment: Yes. What's the syntax? I'll approve an answer with syntax.

Comment: There are code examples on the app request page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/. If you want to do it server side, just post to the /me/apprequests endpoint with message and to parameters  (i don't know c# so i cant write it for you)

Comment: You've answered my question. If you were to form this as an answer I'd accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it the same way you would for any user, just with a target user id of the test user. There are code examples on the [app request page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests). If you want to do it server side, just post to the /me/apprequests endpoint with message and to parameters (i don't know c# so i cant write it for you)

Abby

Comment: Doesn't work for me. POSTing to /me/apprequests ignores the 'to' parameter and seems to create an invitation for the current user. Any updates on this?